# Changing an input field with JS not working

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm stumped as to why when I change the dropdown value, the input field isn't populated with 'testing':

```js
function changeSubject() {
  document.getElementByID('cf7-subject').value = 'testing';
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select onchange="changeSubject()">
    <option value="">Select an Option</option>
    <option value="General Inquiry">General Inquiry</option>
  </select>
  <input id="cf7-subject" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: Please look in browser console for clues from errors thrown

Answer (score 0):

**There are 2 issues in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/po201Lch/2/) above**

1. Replace `getElementByID` --> `getElementById`.

Refere [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) for more info

---

2. In the fiddle, JS is loading after the view is resolved. Hence, the error is thrown in the console that says

*Uncaught ReferenceError: changeSubject is not defined*

**There are 2 options to resolve this error:**

- Option 1 - Inline JavaScript

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeSubject() {
 document.getElementById('cf7-subject').value = 'testing'; 
}
</script>

<form>
    <select id="cf7-selector" onchange="changeSubject()">
        <option value="">
            Select an Option
        </option>
        <option value="General Inquiry">
            General Inquiry
        </option>
    </select>
    <input id="cf7-subject">
    </input>
</form>
```

- Option 2 - Change the value of `LOAD TYPE` in your jsfiddle as shown below

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Happy to help :)